# Declaring income from rent

Tags: income-tax, united-kingdom, rent

Currently I am renting out my flat to my Sister in law. My mortgage is ~£580 a month and here rent is £600. I am not doing this to make money just to cover the mortgage cost. Do I need to declare the ~£20 per month as income? This is £240 a year. From memory I thought there was a threshold that you don't need to declare it as income if under £4k. I may be completely wrong on this count.

So to make the question more generic. In the UK do you need to declare profit from renting a home and is there a threshold if under where you don't need to declare it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DirectGov has a good overview here: http://www.direct.gov.uk/en/MoneyTaxAndBenefits/Taxes/TaxOnPropertyAndRentalIncome/DG_4017814

and answers to your specific questions here: http://www.direct.gov.uk/en/MoneyTaxAndBenefits/Taxes/TaxOnPropertyAndRentalIncome/DG_10013435

In short, you do need to declare the rental income on your tax return and will need to pay tax on it (and note that only the mortgage *interest* (not the full repayment) is deductible as an "allowable expense", see the full list of what is deductible here: http://www.direct.gov.uk/en/MoneyTaxAndBenefits/Taxes/TaxOnPropertyAndRentalIncome/DG_10014027 ).